# Random models not registering in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have 5 models in one of my apps

Report
ReportData
Customer
..etc

For some reason, every since my last deployment, I can no longer change or create new 'Report' or 'Customer' objects, but everything else works?  Any idea why this would be happening?  The admin page just outputs nothing on the /add link and the /change link outputs nothing as well.

Django==1.9.1

I have tried restarting servers, running migrations, and restarting database.  The development version works fine.  Such a strange problem.

Comment: What does your `admin.py` file look like? Maybe the file got wiped and the models aren't being registered.

Comment: try removing .pyc files -- sometimes helps. ``cd myapp``` ```find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;``` Then restart your server.